# How do I disable adblocking in safari?

Tags: safari, adblock

I am using Version 12.1 (13607.1.40.1.5) of Safari.

If I go to Safari->Preferences->Extensions is shows that I have no extensions installed.

When I visit http://kmlviewer.nsspot.net, I press the "choose file" button and select a kml file. I then get the message:

"Please disable the adblock for free use."

If I go to Safari->Settings for This Website, "Enable Content Blockers" is unchecked, "Auto-Play" is set to "Allow all auto-play", and "Pop-Up Windows" is set to "Allow"

I do not see any other settings that would further disable ad blocking. Is there anything more I can do?

There are several sample kml files out there, but you can take the text from:

https://gist.github.com/EricG-Personal/589b293297f42759ba32dea3df04a7b5

and create your own .kml file easily.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page in Safari by holding down the refresh button and selecting 'Reload Without Content Blockers'?